# How to thank a person when he agreed to collaborate

Tags: word-usage, email

I want to say "thank you" to a person that agreed to collaborate in my research.

I thought about writing **"I am glad to know you agreed to collaborate..."**, but it sounds a little cumbersome. I want it to be a slightly informal because the person is a student exactly like me.

Comment: "I appreciate your help."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be:

> I am looking forward to working (together/with you).

using either "together" or "with you".

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be:

"Thanks for your help with this project!"

Answer (score 2):

You might as well write

**"I appreciate your intention to help with this project. Thanks a lot!"**

Answer (score 1):

(I believe minimal changes are the most useful, so I'll start with your sentence and modify it slightly, rather than starting from scratch.)

**"I'm so glad you agreed to collaborate..."**

OR

**"I was [so] glad to hear you agreed to collaborate..."**

These are less formal, more natural versions of the sentence you proposed.

Note, *so* makes a sentence more effusive (enthusiastic).